# String decompression for minimum amount of memory usage C++

Tags: c++, string, memory, compression

So the task I'm struggling to implement, using minimum amount of memory, is string decompression.
Basically, the program reads the compressed string from a text file and spits out the decompressed version of the string in another text file. However, it is recommended to avoid using recursion.

The string might have group of symbols which are fenced with parentheses and in front of the opening bracket there is a number that determines how many times the fenced chunk will be repeated (The groups can be nested).

*Example: 3(AB2(CD)) => ABCDCDABCDCDABCDCD*

My approach, so far, is to read the symbols from the compressed string one by one and to determine whether or not should I add them to the decompressed string or not.

The memory problem that I'm trying to solve is how to decompress a string such as:
*100000000(100000000(AB100000(CD)))*

```
std::ifstream compressed;
char symbol;
while (compressed)
        {

        symbol = compressed.peek();
            if (symbol >= '0'&&symbol <= '9')
            {
                //code
            }
            if (symbol == '(')
            {
                //code
            }
            if (symbol == ')')
            {
                //code
            }
            if (symbol != ')' && symbol != '(' && (symbol <= '0' || symbol >= '9'))
            {
                //code
            }

        }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide some of your code or an [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @RobertS-ReinstateMonica is that understandable enough?

Comment: Yes, i think so. Thanks for the edit. This will help you get better answers. Welcome to Stackoverflow by the way!

Comment: Initially, I'd not discount use of recursion at least for some parts of the solution. Consider the input a simple programming language that only supports print statements and loops. Parse the input into an abstract syntax tree (recursive descent parser seems a valid approach). Then evaluate the AST -- a print node writes a symbol to the output file, loop node evaluates the contained sequence of nodes repeatedly.

Comment: @DanMašek  Thanks, I'll give it a shot!

Comment: @user10574164 No problem. Here's a quick draft of what i had in mind: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c3e7cf97b9092c8f

Comment: However, if you really want to minimize memory usage (trading it off for much more work to be done), then another option comes to mind. You keep a stack of pairs (repetition count, file offset). When you come to a repetition, you pop count and current offset to stack. When you reach end of repetition, you decrease count on top of the stack. If still non-zero, return to file offset and continue processing from there, if zero, pop from stack and continue parsing.

Comment: @user10574164 Here's an example of the second approach: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3e847d8a42fb195d

Comment: @DanMašek aw man, thanks for your effort. Even though I'll have to research some of the code (the smart pointers especially) I'm grateful, thanks!